# Using groovy script to set authorization to basic in SoapUI

Tags: groovy, soapui

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aKCsd.png)

I am using groovyscript to run and test SOAP messages to my server. I need my messages to have the basic authorization. I know you can do this manually using the tab under the soap message. I can enter my username and PW using the TestRequest Properties, however I can't find a way to set the auth to basic. I tried editing the 'Authentication Type' property to "Global GTTP Settings", which is the value it's given when I set basic auth manually. As you can see in the code, there are no errors running it and it eddits PW, username, but not Auth Type. Is there a way to either change the property so the message has a basic Auth, or a different way to set basic auth with a UN and PW? The goal is to be able to test several SOAP messages while setting the authentication to basic and give it the UN and PW.

Code/Groovy Script:

```
def TR = 
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.testCases["Get"].testSteps["getEmployee"]
TR.setPropertyValue("Username","usernamehere")
TR.setPropertyValue("Password","passwordgoeshere")
TR.setPropertyValue("Authentication Type","Global HTTP Settings")
log.info "done"
```

Current result: changed UN and PW properties, can't change the Authentication Type property.

**Goal: give the SOAP message Basic Auth using groovy script**

Comment: That doesn't look like an authorization error.  It looks like you're getting a response containing `testStep` (singular) but you're trying to access `testSteps` (plural).

Comment: Yea, Groovy doesn't read the "Authentication Type" property as an existing property. So I can't edit that property like I could with username and password. The code above line 4 is correct, and it successfully edits those two properties.

Comment: TR object is of a type `WsdlTestRequestStep`, and on this object, You try again get `WsdlTestRequestStep` object(by calling `TR.testSteps["getEmployee"]` ) which obvoiusly cause above error.

Comment: Ty snieguu! I found that issue and fixed it. It still won't edit the authentication type property, so I'm still unable to change the authorization to basic with groovy script. I edited the question to make the issue more clear.

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation? https://www.soapui.org/soap-and-wsdl/authenticating-soap-requests.html

Comment: I explained that I can set auth manually...which is what is outlined in the documentation... nothing in the SoapUI documentation acknowledges automation using groovy or java script.

Answer (score 1):

could you, please, try and check this solution?

```
def httpRequest = context.testCase.getTestStepByName("test_step").getHttpRequest();

httpRequest.setSelectedAuthProfileAndAuthType("Basic", com.eviware.soapui.config.CredentialsConfig.AuthType.PREEMPTIVE);
httpRequest.setUsername("username");
httpRequest.setPassword("password");
```

here is the link to the API of this class:
https://www.soapui.org/apidocs/com/eviware/soapui/impl/support/AbstractHttpRequest.html

Marek